# Tkinter: gridding canvas objects and buttons together

Tags: python, button, tkinter, grid, frame

I would like to display 9 Set Cards in a Frame.  Under each card will be it's own button.  I'm using the SetCard.deal_card(position) method to place a card in the Frame in a 3x3 grid (position 0-8).  When I run the program, only the buttons appear.  When I comment out the pickButton.grid() method, then the cards appear.  I don't know why I can only have one and not both.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class SetCard(Canvas):

    def __init__(self,master,number,color,shape,shading):
        # create a 60x60 white canvas with a 5-pixel grooved border
        Canvas.__init__(self,master,width=100,height=160,bg='white',\
                        bd=5,relief=RAISED) #also relief = SUNKEN
        # store the valuelist and colorlist
        self.number = number
        self.color = color
        self.shape = shape
        self.shading = shading
        self.selected=False
        self.pickButton=Button(self,text="Pick me!", command=self.toggle_card)

    def deal_card(self,position):
        '''puts the given card into a position on the 3x3 grid of the frame'''
        self.draw_card()
        print("row: ",(position//3)*2)
        print("col: ",position%3)
        self.grid(row=(position//3)*2,column=position%3)
        self.pickButton.grid(row=((position//3)*2)+1,column= position %3)
        self.master.deck.pop(0)

    def toggle_card(self):
        self.selected=True
        self['bg']='gray'
        self['relief']=sunken

    def draw_card(self):
        '''draws the pips in the correct locations on the card'''
        # clear old pips first
        self.erase()
        # location of which pips should be drawn
        if self.number == 1:
            self.draw_pip(position=2)
        if self.number == 2:
            self.draw_pip(position=1)
            self.draw_pip(position=3)
        if self.number == 3:
            self.draw_pip(position=1)
            self.draw_pip(position=2)
            self.draw_pip(position=3)

    def draw_pip(self,position):
        '''draws a single pip in the given location'''
        if self.shading=='solid':
            inside=self.color
        else:
            inside=''
        (topx,topy) = (55,10+ (position-1)*50)      
        if self.shape == 'diamond':
            self.create_polygon(topx, topy, topx+15, topy+20, topx, topy+40, topx-15, topy+20,\
                                outline=self.color,fill=inside,width=3)
            if self.shading=='stripe':
                incrementxy=[(5,30),(10,25), (15,20), (10,15), (5,10)]
                for xy in incrementxy:
                    self.create_line(topx-xy[0],topy+xy[1],topx+xy[0],topy+xy[1],fill=self.color)
        if self.shape == 'circle':
            self.create_oval(topx-20,topy,topx+20,topy+40,fill=inside,outline=self.color,width=3)
            if self.shading=='stripe':
                incrementxy=[(10,3),(14,7),(17,10),(19,14),(20,20),(18,24),(17,30),(14,33),(10,37)]
                for xy in incrementxy:
                    self.create_line(topx-xy[0],topy+xy[1],topx+xy[0],topy+xy[1], fill= self.color)
        if self.shape == 'square':
            self.create_polygon(topx-20,topy,topx+20,topy,topx+20,topy+40,topx-20,topy+40,fill=inside,outline=self.color,width=3)
            if self.shading=='stripe':
                for increment in range(5,40,5):
                    self.create_line(topx-20, topy+increment,topx+20,topy+increment, fill = self.color)


    def erase(self):
        '''erases all the pips'''
        pipList = self.find_all()
        for pip in pipList:
            self.delete(pip)

class SetGameFrame(Frame):
    '''frame for a game of Set'''

    def __init__(self,master):
        '''creates a new Set frame'''
        # set up Frame object
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        colorList=['red','green','magenta']
        shadingList=['solid','stripe','open']
        shapeList=['circle','diamond','square']
        self.dealt_cards=[]
        self.deck=[]
        for number in range(3):
            for color in colorList:
                for shading in shadingList:
                    for shape in shapeList:
                        self.deck.append(SetCard(self,number+1,color,shape,shading))
        random.shuffle(self.deck)
        for position in range(9):
            self.deck[0].deal_card(position)
            self.dealt_cards.append(self.deck[0])
        self.setButton=Button(self,text="SET!",command=self.pick_set)
        self.setButton.grid(row=6,column=1,rowspan=2)

    def pick_set(self):
        pass

def play_Set():
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Set Game')
    game = SetGameFrame(root)
    root.mainloop()

play_Set()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is in making the pick buttons slaves of the cards instead of the canvas.
Change the definition to

`self.pickButton=Button(master,text="Pick me!", command=self.toggle_card)`

and your code will work.  What's happening with the code as you have it, is that the card is getting gridded in the canvas, but then the button is getting gridded in the card, and all you see is the button.

It seems natural (at least to me) that the first parameter (master) would be self, since the button is an attribute of the card.  However, the widget hierarchy in Tk (the GUI toolkit underlying tkinter) has nothing to do with this.  The first parameter here doesn't mean that self.PickButton is a child of master in the objected-oriented sense, but that master (the canvas widget) is managing self-pickButton's "geometry".

By the way, there's a syntax error in your code.  At line 30, there should be quotation marks about the word "sunken."

Comment: I think your statement "tkinter isn't object oriented" isn't correct. Tkinter widgets are indeed objects: you define them via classes, they inherit attributes from superclasses, and they have attributes and methods. That makes it highly object-oriented.

Comment: I didn't say tkinter, I said Tk.  tkinter is an object-oriented wrapper around Tk, which is not itself object-oriented.

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't see how that has any relevance here, since tkinter is object oriented. The parent/child hierarchy is unrelated to whether it's object oriented or not. I think your comments related to that will be confusing to people trying to learn how to use tkinter.

Comment: Well it seems to have confused you, but when I was learning tkinter I was confused precisely because the object hierarchy has nothing to do with the OO hierarchy.  It seemed to me that the OP was having the same problem, and I was trying to point it out to him.  I'll try to edit my explanation to be more explicit, thanks.